# accept leading number in input field

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<input type="number" name = "search_number" id="search_number"  pattern="[0-9]\d*"  class="form-control form-control-sm">
```

when adding number `00107` it takes only `107`, is there any solution that it takes `00107` instead of `107` and if we input `107` it take it as `107` I don't want to add default 00 in input because database contain some data that don't contain `00`. if anyone has any solution kindly answer me.

Comment: Yes, make it type="text" or move the 00 outside the field

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text box` with custom validation. Here `isNumberKey` only accept the number for each character

```js
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}

function show(){
  console.log(document.getElementById('test').value)
}
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/>

<button type="button" value="show value" onClick="show()">show value</button>
```